# Why the upper limit in breakpoints in material UI for xs is sm?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, angular-material

I am new to material UI but I am learning, one thing that I was looking into is breakpoints.

Now, this is what my breakpoints look like.

```
breakpoints: createBreakpoints({
    keys: [
      "xs",
      "sm",
      "md",
      "lg",
      "xl",
    ],
    values: {
      xs: 0, 
      sm: 600,
      md: 960,
      lg: 1280,
      xl: 1920,
    },
  }),
```

I did a `console.log(theme.breakpoints.between('xs', 'sm')`, and the output I got surprised me since it was 0 to **960**, I don't understand. Shouldn't it be 0 to 600?

So, I did `console.log(theme.breakpoints.between('xs', 'xs')` and the output i got was 0 to 600.

Why is this happening and how is this even logical?
I am so confused.

Comment: breakpoints are talking about range. xs is `0-600` and  sm is `600 - 960`. And you are using between, so it would take the min of start, which is 0 and max of end, which is 960.

Comment: @Horst, the problem is with using functions such as down or up where if I use `down('sm')` it should be below 600 which isn't the case. What is the point of defining `xs`.